# What is the use of request.setAttribute in Java?

Tags: java

I can understand that it's like assigning a value to a key.
For ex: request.setAttribute("listedit", people);

where people is a string. How it will assign people to "listedit" and where/how the key should be used?

Comment: Please try to ask a clear question. Give more details. Currently, I have no idea what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

It's just an attribute `Map`. Most commonly your view (JSP or other) will access the values by key, so you can write something like `Hello ${name}` in your view, and the value bound to the key "name" will then be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

request.setAttribute only make the key available in the following jsp page.

For example, the flow like page1->page2, if we use request.setAttribute in page1, then only page2 can get the key value set in page2.

request.setAttribute():
1.May help you in getting rid of the hidden fields.
2.Use it most of times when you just need the attribute just for the consecutive page.